# Tinymce - problem with fontsize using bbcodes

Tags: tinymce, font-size, bbcode

i am using tinymce with the bbcodes-plugin. In generally, its working nicely, most of the bbcodes like [b] and [color] and so forth are transmitted into html within the textarea and safed as bbcodes into the database correctly.

The thing with font-size is the following, when formating a string the first time it is correctly changing its size and is safed correctly as bbcode into the database. 
But when i open that record again to edit it, the bbcode is not converted to html, so in the textarea there is something like

"[size= medium]rfeferf[/size]" instead of the text in the right size.

Do you have any hints on this? Ive been searching the web yesterday and today, didnt find anything that could solve this.

Regards, Maschek

Comment: ok, got it working, by using serversided regular expressions, which are applied to the row-content bevor being loaded into the textarea.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by BBCode plugin in TinyMCE unable to transform [size] tag back to HTML. I've logged [a TinyMCE bug #5327 with a fix patch attached](http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=5327). You can download latest TinyMCE source, apply the patch and compile it (or wait until the patch is reviewed and released).

The related source code is located at plugins/bbcode/editor_plugin_src.js